# How to receive simple one-line user input with nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin, prompt, v8

I want to run a nodeJS application with my own very simple console, so my question is how can I achieve it in a straightforward way (typical of any programming language).

I've seen articles like [How To Read User Input With NodeJS](http://st-on-it.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-read-user-input-with-nodejs.html) but I am not sure if there is a simple way already included.

Comment: I found that the best approach to do it, changing the original requirment, is to open a line oriented socket/stream using https://github.com/jonseymour/node-lines-adapter and to use the console connect via telnet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks unfinished, but it appears NodeJS *does* have a simpler way with its [Readline library](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/readline.html) in version 5.3.

Other than that, I think the article you linked to covers the basics pretty well.